# Defining key for derived entities from base Entity

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, inheritance, ef-model-first

I want to derive `TimeCondition` entity from `Condition` entity, so I created this model (with abstract `Condition`):

[image]

but on validation, it says:

> Error  3   Error 159: EntityType 'SHomeModel.Store.TimeCondition' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.  E:\proj\SmartHome.edmx  126

How can I define `TimeCondition`'s key to be `Condition`'s `Id` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your table in database should have primary key but in EDMX file you should remove it from your child entity to let it to use parent's key!

[More details on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj618293)

Answer (score -1):

You have to give Condition's Id to the TimeCondidtion as a foreign key. And then update the Entity model.